# Compiled Elf binary is too big

Tags: c++, c

```c
long *video_memory = (long *)0xB8000;

int main() {
    // long *video_memory = (long *)0xB8000;
    *video_memory = 0x5050505050505050;
    return 0;
}
```

Why this C code above creates a **2Mb** binary file when I link it?

If I comment the global var and uncomment the local one it works (the file has then has just a few bytes).

This is how I link/[cross-]compile it:

```sh
x86_64-elf-gcc -m64 -ffreestanding -nostdlib -mno-red-zone -c kernel.c -o bin/kernel.o
objcopy --remove-section .eh_frame bin/kernel.o
x86_64-elf-ld --oformat binary -Ttext 0x8000 bin/kernel_entry.o bin/kernel.o -o bin/kernel.bin
#  kernel.bin is now 2Mb
```

Comment: "too big" for what? your expectations? Examine the link map produced by the linker, will show you the size of each region. Compare that with the link map for the smaller binary, you can see what's changed.

Comment: you might also try stripping your executable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the linker has the ridiculous `max-page-size` of 2MB from a mistake in the x86_64 ABI, which ends up inducing 2MB alignment requirements in various places. Normally it will put text and data segments in the same part of the file, with the intent that it be mapped twice, but that's only possible with a reasonable binary format like ELF that can represent it; with a raw binary, the only way it can achieve the alignment is with a nearly-2MB gap.

The right fix is to override the ridiculous default `max-page-size` with `-z max-page-size=4096` (the actual hardware page size/granularity of memory protection) on the link command line. If you use the compiler driver rather than invoking `ld` directly, that's `-Wl,-z,max-page-size=4096`. Modern hosted toolchains do this for you whenever you use the hardening options that would make the same issue appear, but apparently bare-metal still doesn't.

You might also consider using a bootloader that can load ELF, rather than a raw binary, for your kernel. ELF loaders are easy to write and let you do useful things like avoid the wasted space by mapping (at a bare metal level, just loading/copying) the same page twice, have an entry point at a location controlled by the image headers rather than hard-coded in the bootloader, etc. You can even make your kernel position-independent this way if you like.

Comment: That flag decresed the size of the file, but the characters are not print :(

Comment: @Fabricio: That's a separate question. Looking at your actual code, you have x86_64 code attempting to access legacy real-mode PC bus addresses for video output, you haven't done anything to set the entry point (first byte of `.text` might not be first byte of `main`), you're returning to nowhere (what do you expect to happen after `return 0;`? probably should end with `for(;;)` instead), etc. Fixing all this is osdev questions that should be asked separately.

Comment: yes, ill accept your anwser, but if I uncomment it works, so I thought it should work too once I get a small bin. And yes I have an entrypoint that calls main and halt

Comment: @Fabricio: OK. For just the local/global variable distinction, it's possible that the compiler generates some construct for accessing the global that doesn't work right without some setup/relocations. Why not read the disassembly and see?

Comment: I like the idea of an ELF loader.  Never considered it before. +1

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I changed `-z max-page-size=4096` to `-z max-page-size=1` and it worked! No idea why tho.

Comment: @Fabricio: You really need to look at the root cause. That's not a correct fix or even valid.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE My second try: I built a linker script with all the sections inside the .text section, then I extracted the text section with `objcopy -j .text -O binary bin/kernel.bin bin/kernel.bin` and it works :) But yeah, I'll look at the elf loader approach. Ty!

Comment: Could you please tell more about the "mistake in the x86_64 ABI, which ends up inducing 2MB alignment requirements in various places"? I'm studying the insides of ELF and my copy of the PDF doesn't seem to say anything about section alignment, but `ld` *does* align at 2MB borders by default for some reason...